# Generate output only if other command already generated output

Tags: bash, cron, output

In this bash script, I update all apps inside all my Nextcloud docker instances:

```
#!/bin/bash
ALL_NC="next1.mycloud.com next2.mycloud.com next3.mycloud.com"
for i in $ALL_NC; do
  DOCKERIMAGE="${i//.}_app_1";
  # TODO: echo this only if something happens
  # echo "check $DOCKERIMAGE"
  for a in $(docker exec --user www-data ${DOCKERIMAGE} php occ app:list|grep Disabled -B999|grep -- -|cut -d" " -f4|cut -d: -f1|xargs); do
    docker exec --user www-data ${DOCKERIMAGE} php occ app:update $a
  done
done
exit 0
```

This creates output like

```
news new version available: 14.2.2
news updated
news new version available: 14.2.2
news updated
news new version available: 14.2.2
news updated
```

This is called by `cron` which automatically mails to root if the script generates any output.

How can I activate the line that should echo only if something is being updated?

Comment: How do you know if something will happen  or has happened?

Comment: `docker exec...` will only create the output if something is updated

Answer (score 0):

You can put whatever portion of your code into `$(...)` to capture the output instead of writing it to standard out.

For example:

```bsh
OUT="$(
  for i in 1 2 3; do
    echo "updated $i"
  done
)"
if [[ "$OUT" == *"updated"* ]]; then
  echo "$OUT"
fi
```

Note: use the double square-brackets `[[]]` and the simple comparison operator (i.e. `==`)